# PowerShell report on applied windows updates after a date

Tags: windows, powershell, report, updates

I'm trying to get information on which Windows updates are installed on Windows Server 2003 and 2008 servers via SCCM v12 from a given date. For this I'm using PowerShell's `Get-Hotfix` cmdlet.

However I've run into an issue which I'll now explain:

```
Get-HotFix -ComputerName SERVER01 | where-object {$_.hotfixid -ne "file 1"}  | Select description,hotfixid,installedby,InstalledOn | sort installedon
```

Returns the hotfixes but not many with dates. I know this is an issue, so to resolve that you need to run it like this:

```
Get-HotFix -ComputerName SERVER01 | where-object {$_.hotfixid -ne "file 1"}  | Select description,hotfixid,installedby,@{l="InstalledOn";e={[DateTime]::Parse($_.psbase.properties["installedon"].value,$([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US")))}}  | sort installedon
```

This then returns most with dates....but not all. So next I want to get updates only installed from a certain date, so I run this to do that.

```
$date = Get-Date '26/07/2013'

Get-HotFix -ComputerName SERVER01 | where-object {$_.hotfixid -ne "file 1"}  | where "InstalledOn" -gt $date  | Select description,hotfixid,installedby,@{l="InstalledOn";e={[DateTime]::Parse($_.psbase.properties["installedon"].value,$([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US")))}} | sort installedon
```

But this does not return any updates or error. However I know there are updates that have been applied since this date as I see them in the second commands results.

So question is am I doing something wrong? and is there another way via SCCM?

Comment: where "InstalledOn" -gt $date  should be where "InstalledOn" -le $date,   you won't find a data installed later than today.

Comment: Thanks but that outputs all. I need to get HotFixes installed after the $date

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-HotFix -ComputerName SERVER01 | where-object {$_.hotfixid -ne "file 1"} | Select description,hotfixid,installedby,@{l="InstalledOn";e={[DateTime]::Parse($_.psbase.properties["installedon"].value,$([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US")))}} | where-object {$_.installedon –gt $date} | sort installedon -descending
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over complicating things:

```
get-hotfix | Where-Object {$_.installedon -gt (get-date).addmonths(-2)} | Sort-Object -property installedon -Descending
```